# Firestore query with timestamp

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am able to fetch the data using where condition if it's a text field but when I am trying to do the same with timestamp field and date things are not working.

Here is my code:

`home.ts`

```
firebase.firestore().collection("cities").where("timestamp", ">", "3/24/2020")
    .onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {
        var cities = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            cities.push(doc.data().name);
        });
        console.log("Timestamp greather than 3/24/2020 -- ", cities.join(", "));
    });
```

Everything works fine with `firebase.firestore().collection("cities").where("state", "==", "CA")` but not working with `date`.

Screenshot of fire storage:

[image]

Note: `JLD` doc should be returned in console because its `timestamp` value is greater than `3/24/2020`

### Edit 1

As guided by @alex now I am doing like this

`let start = new Date('2020-03-25');`
`firebase.firestore().collection("cities").where("timestamp", ">", start)`

but it is including the data of `2020-03-25` when I am using `>`, why ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I am trying to do the same with the timestamp field and date things are not working.

It's not working because you are passing to the `.where("timestamp", ">", "3/24/2020")` a String which is not correct since your `timestamp` property in the database holds a `Date` object and **not** a String. To solve this, instead of passing the date as a String ("3/24/2020") pass it as a Date object and everything will work fine.

```
let timestamp = new Date('2020-03-25');
```

And then use:

```
firebase.firestore().collection("cities").where("timestamp", ">", timestamp);
```

Comment: I am trying, i'll get back

Comment: `new Date('2020-03-25') `creates a date with the hour, minutes and seconds having the value of `00`. Since your date in the database has the hour set to **4 PM**, you are getting the correct behavior.

Comment: i didnt get you, with `new Date('2020-03-25')` i am getting a record of `2020-03-25` too, how do i avoid this ?

Comment: When you create a Date object passing **only** the year, month and day, then the hour, minutes and seconds are set to `00`. It's the same as creating a Date object like this: `new Date('2020-03-25 00:00:00')`. Since your Date object in the database has the hour to 4 PM, it's normal to get that as a result, because 4 PM is after `00:00:00`, right?

Comment: thanks a lot, can i ask you something, i am trying to learn queries in firestore and i am facing few small issues, if possible can i connect with you on skype,hangout,slack anywhere , if you can give a little guidance when i stuck..I will not disturb you

Comment: I'm sorry but I am available only here, on Stackoverflow. If you will post new questions, we'll take a look and try to help you.

Comment: alright, thank you, i am inching slowly and slowly :)